# import python module when using mod_python

Tags: python, web-services, mod-python, imdb

i have been using imdbpy for some time. I was interested in making a very basic webservice to return json data.

I have a basic system working earlier today however after a reboot i now get the following error 
AssertionError: Import cycle in /home/prog/www/imdb/imdb.py.

the code is being ran using mod_python. which 100% works.
the following lines seem to be the problem

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import imdb
from mod_python import apache

def handler(req):
        req.content_type = "text/plain"
        req.write("test")
        return apache.OK
```

if i comment the import imdb test is printed.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this could be the problem: You named your file "imdb.py". Rename it and the problem could be solved.

Explication: When importing imdb, python finds your module before finding the imdb-package that you initially wanted to import (because current folder is listed in PYTHONPATH before the the standard python library). So basically you import yourself.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have pulled my hair out trying to get that to work. It is such an obvious mistake that i was blinded. Many thanks.

Comment: Don't blame yourself. This is the most frequent cause of errors reported by python developers on SO...